# Dynamic form action,is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have 3 buttons on my toolbar (delete,block,unblock). Сan i change form action dynamically

```
 <form action="/users/groupUnblock" method="POST">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Tried to write a func,but its not working

Comment: Can you show us the function you used, and explain what wasn't working (was there a console error, did nothing happen regarding the action change, etc)?

Comment: You can in theory dynamically change the action, but there are much better ways to do this. Why not use a function to determine which button was clicked, then make a corresponding `fetch` request?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use JavaScript at all, this can be done with pure HTML5. You can specify the action of each button with the `formaction` attribute.

Example:

```html
<form>
    <button type="submit" formaction="http://firsttarget.com">Submit to first</button>
    <button type="submit" formaction="http://secondtarget.com">Submit to second</button>
</form>
```

Read more about this attribute [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formaction.asp)

Comment: +1 Nice and concise answer. Note that [the _de facto_ docs for web-technologies](https://www.w3.org/blog/2017/10/w3c-to-work-with-mdn-on-web-platform-documentation/) is [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/), and that [**w3schools is not affiliated with W3C**](https://www.w3schools.com/about/). I also think that the official specs themselves occasionally do a nice job of explaining, e.g. for `formaction`: ["URL to use on form submission"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fs-formaction).